# How to merge multiple jQuery functions that enable/disable fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery, switch-statement

I have these jQuery functions that I would like to put into one function, instead of breaking them apart like I have them. Basically, when I choose one choice from a drop down, I want to enable/disable further choices. How would I go about doing so?

```
        //To disable "Your Center" Drop Down if "Customer Care Center" is not chosen.
    $('select[name="YourLocation"]').change(function () {

        if ($(this).val() === 'Customer Care Center') {
            $('[name="YourCenter"]').prop("disabled", false);
        }
        else {
            $('[name="YourCenter"]').prop("disabled", true);
        }
    });

    //To disable "BranchNumber, RegionNumber, & DivisionNumber" if "Branch" is not chosen.
    $('select[name="YourLocation"]').change(function () {

        if ($(this).val() === 'Branch') {
            $('[name="BranchNumber"]').prop("disabled", false);
            $('[name="RegionNumber"]').prop("disabled", false);
            $('[name="DivisionNumber"]').prop("disabled", false);
        }
        else {
            $('[name="BranchNumber"]').prop("disabled", true);
            $('[name="RegionNumber"]').prop("disabled", true);
            $('[name="DivisionNumber"]').prop("disabled", true);
        }
    });

    //To disable "RegionNumber & DivisionNumber" if "Region" is not chosen.
    $('select[name="YourLocation"]').change(function () {

        if ($(this).val() === 'Region') {
            $('[name="RegionNumber"]').prop("disabled", false);
            $('[name="DivisionNumber"]').prop("disabled", false);
        }
        else {
            $('[name="BranchNumber"]').prop("disabled", true);
            $('[name="RegionNumber"]').prop("disabled", true);
            $('[name="DivisionNumber"]').prop("disabled", true);
        }
    });

    //To disable "DivisionNumber" if "Division" is not chosen.
    $('select[name="YourLocation"]').change(function () {

        if ($(this).val() === 'Division') {
            $('[name="DivisionNumber"]').prop("disabled", false);
        }
        else {
            $('[name="BranchNumber"]').prop("disabled", true);
            $('[name="RegionNumber"]').prop("disabled", true);
            $('[name="DivisionNumber"]').prop("disabled", true);
        }
    });
```

Comment: what is this `@*To`?

Comment: It's just a comment, in Visual Studio I'm using @* comment here *@ instead of // or <!-- -->

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('select[name="YourLocation"]').change(function () {
    $('[name="YourCenter"]').prop("disabled", $(this).val() != 'Customer Care Center')
    $('[name="DivisionNumber"]').prop("disabled", $(this).val() == 'Customer Care Center');
    $('[name="RegionNumber"]').prop("disabled", $(this).val() == 'Customer Care Center' || $(this).val() == 'Division');
    $('[name="BranchNumber"]').prop("disabled", $(this).val() != 'Branch');
})
```